# C# WinRT Make a Control size fill its parent

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, grid-layout

I'm an experienced developer, but new to C# and the Windows Runtime. I'm trying to create a custom UserControl (a specialized button) that can be dynamically sized. My button should have three rows of text on it (Top, Middle, Bottom) which are given proportional sizes (1*, 3*, 1*). I want the textboxes to fill their given space in the grid. i.e. If the button is 500x200, then the internal TextBoxes would all be 200 wide, the Top one would be 100 pixels tall, the Middle would be 300 tall, and the bottom would be 100 tall. If the button is 700x300, Top=140, Middle=420, Bottom=140.

I created a Grid with proportionally sized Rows and it behaves the way I want, but I don't know how to get the child elements in the grid to fill their space in the grid cell.

[image]

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="DynamicButtons.DynamicButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:DynamicButtons"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="SlateGray">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Text="Top" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="Middle" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add VerticalAlignment="Stretch" to your TextBox definitions, they'll fill the vertical space.

Comment: gah! When I tried that in the XAML editor it didn't work, but when I tried setting that in the UI Properties editor THEN it worked. Thanks!